# SearchView searching through TextViews

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I am trying to implement a SearchView for my app. All the Tutorials I saw are implementing the searchView for a ListView. Is it possible to use it for a bunch of TextViews also? And if so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `SearchView` has nothing to do with `ListView` or any other specific type of UI. `SearchView` is a widget, not that different from an `EditText`. It is up to a developer to decide what to do when the user types something into a `SearchView`. So, you need to decide what to do when the user types something into the `SearchView` that somehow affects your "bunch of TextViews". We cannot tell you how to do that, because we do not know what you want nor what your "bunch of TextViews" is.

Comment: Ah, I see. Guess I can work with that, thank you!